Ansible how to pass result of first task to block of tasks in other file
I have a task as below :
-name : Set-up 
 shell: abc
 register: "{{item }}_result"
 loop: {{ setu }}
-name: set of tasks
 include_tasks: abc.yml
 when "'{{ item }}_result'.rc!=0"
 loop: {{ setu }}
 

abc.yml

   - name: step1
     shell: {{ item.set }}
   - name: step2
     shell: {{ item.sertt }}


Here the first task is expected to run for all items of setu. So how do I capture the result of shell command for all items in a variable and loop the task file for all the items and also while checking that for item1 result.rc ! =0 and similarly for item2 result.rc!=0 and so on

A variable registered in a loop is a dictionary that always keeps the results list in the attribute results. See Registering variables with a loop. For example,
    - shell: echo {{ item }}_result
      register: out
      loop: [a, b, c]

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"

gives abridged
  msg: a_result
  msg: b_result
  msg: c_result

It is not possible to loop a block. See Playbook Keywords. Instead, you can loop either include_tasks or import_tasks. See Including and Importing. Put the tasks you want to iterate into a file. For example,
shell> cat abc.yml 
- debug:
    msg: step1 {{ item.stdout }}
- debug:
    msg: step2 {{ item.stdout }}

and iterate include_tasks
    - include_tasks: abc.yml
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"

gives abridged
  msg: step1 a_result
  msg: step2 a_result
  msg: step1 b_result
  msg: step2 b_result
  msg: step1 c_result
  msg: step2 c_result



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - shell: echo {{ item }}_result
      register: out
      loop: [a, b, c]

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"

    - include_tasks: abc.yml
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"



Q: Check that item result.rc !=0
A: Any rc != 0 makes the task fail. You have to ignore_errors. For example,
    - shell: "{{ item }}"
      register: out
      loop: ['true', 'false', 'true']
      ignore_errors: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.rc }}"
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"

gives abridged
  msg: '0'
  msg: '1'
  msg: '0'

Now, you can conditionally iterate the tasks
    - include_tasks: abc.yml
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      when: item.rc != 0
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"

gives abridged
skipping: [localhost] => (item=true) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=true) 
included: /export/scratch/tmp1/test-44/abc.yml for localhost => (item=false)

  msg: 'step1 '
  msg: 'step2 



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - shell: "{{ item }}"
      register: out
      loop: ['true', 'false', 'true']
      ignore_errors: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.rc }}"
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"

    - include_tasks: abc.yml
      loop: "{{ out.results }}"
      when: item.rc != 0
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.cmd }}"



Thank you for your answer and detailed explanation. I just did not get 1 point - like in my case I want to check if my registered output for each item .rc!=0 so how can I do that? and also for loop I want to loop around my dictionary - setu

Any rc!=0 makes the task to fail. The attribute results is a list of whatever you loop.

Like I want to skip task every time if the result.rc is 0 and only proceed if it is not zero. For example - like I need to do mounting for 6 filesystems using LVM.  setu which has filesystem name, volume group, physical_volume etc for 6 filesystems. So I want to run this loop of LVM steps for 6 times  but that should only be executed when results.rc!=0 for each filesystem

I added an example. Fit it to your case.
